# Ffmpeg iis smooth streaming credentials

Tags: iis, ffmpeg, smooth-streaming

I use ffmpeg to stream live video to IIS publishing point by this command

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="video device name":audio="audio device name" -pix_fmt yuv420p -f ismv http://localhost/test.isml
```

And it works properly. But when my publishing point has credentials - ffmpeg fails in one minute after starting with

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error
```

As I see I need to specify IIS publishing point credentials. But how? Any ideas?

Comment: When I use you command line I got many lines including :"Past duration 0.781242 too large" and "real-time buffer [BisonCam, NB Pro] [video input] too full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!". Didyou solve your issue?